# Syntax of Terminal Commands

Tags: command-line, git

The syntax of a Terminal command will be something like the following:

```
command -option argument
```

But the following Git command seems irregular, can anyone explain the syntax of it. (Why two commands? Why two arguments?)

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

In short because `git`'s configuration is a simple key/value database. To change the configuration, you need to tell it both the config key and the new value.

As for syntax, as long as it doesn't interfere with the Bash syntax, anything goes. The reason some people use named arguments (as opposed to positional arguments) is it makes them easy to be in any order and optional. The parser is completely application specific. One example is [Python's `argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Answer (score 1):

Like many version control systems, git uses a sub-command system. "config" here is the sub-command .. any common options would go before it, and sub-command specific options afterwards, such as --global in this case. The two parameters here, (git) option name and value, are parameters to the config sub-command, not to the --global option (which merely modifies the action of the sub-command.) Two parameters are entirely reasonable here - the name of the git option to be set and the value to set it to.